# Link to website in Gtk.MenuBar using Glade

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, glade

What is the best way to create a menuitem (for the Gtk.MenuBar) that should open the default browser with a new tab and loading an URL?

Is it possible to do that in Glade directly or do I need to create that function in the program code itself? Is there a preferred way in Python 3 to do that?

Comment: I think you can create the Menubar using Glade, But whatever the functionalities you want to associate that should be coded in your program.

Comment: @Sagar: Yeah, I think the Gtk.MenuItem just doesn't have a Glade-only function to link to a website. Only the AboutDialog has a field for an URL which opens the browser without any code calling it. For the Menuitems I now just connected the functions and used webbrowser.open_new_tab() from the standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching for a Glade-only solution, I think that Gtk.Menuitem doesn't have a URL-open option. I now just defined `on_menuitem_clicked`-function that uses:

`webbrowser.open_new_tab()`

from the standard library.